# MySQL Monitoring Script in Shell or Perl for Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, scripting

I need a MySQL Monitoring Script in Bash or Perl for Linux.

I found some but they are quite big with a lots of checks that are not 
useful at all for me and in this case I should customise the script 
a lot.

Any idea for most important parameters of MySQL monitoring in a Shell or Perl
script?

Following parameters should be monitored:

```
qcache_hits                                                     
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;                             
SHOW SESSION STATUS;                                
slow_queries                                                    
max_connections                                         
key_buffer_size
mysql availability  STATUS
Error log
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
max_used_connections
Handler_read%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the things I look at when reviewing a server:

```
(Innodb_buffer_pool_reads) / Uptime   
(Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed) / Uptime   
(Opened_tables) / Uptime 
(Opened_files) / Uptime  
(Opened_table_definitions) / Uptime   
(Qcache_lowmem_prunes) / Uptime  
(Qcache_not_cached) / Uptime 
(Questions) / Uptime 
(Queries) / Uptime   
(Created_tmp_disk_tables) / Uptime    
(Created_tmp_tables) / Uptime
(Handler_read_rnd) / Uptime  
(Com_commit) / Uptime    
(Select_full_join) / Uptime  
(Select_range) / Uptime  
(Select_range_check) / Uptime
(Select_scan) / Uptime   
(Sort_merge_passes) / Uptime 
(Slow_queries) / Uptime  
(Aborted_clients) / Uptime   
(Aborted_connects) / Uptime  
(Connections) / Uptime   
(Threads_created) / Uptime   
(Slow_launch_threads) / Uptime    
(Slave_retried_transactions) / Uptime
(Com_lock_tables) / Uptime   
(Com_rollback) / Uptime  
(Innodb_rows_inserted) / Uptime  
(Innodb_row_lock_waits) / Uptime 
(Innodb_dblwr_writes) / Uptime    
(Innodb_deadlocks) / Uptime  
(Binlog_cache_use) / Uptime  
(Binlog_cache_disk_use) / Uptime 
(Innodb_buffer_pool_reads) / Uptime   
(Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed) / Uptime   
(Innodb_data_fsyncs) / Uptime
(Innodb_os_log_fsyncs) / Uptime  
(Innodb_log_waits) / Uptime  
(Key_reads * 1024 / key_buffer_size) / Uptime 
(Key_reads) / Uptime 
(Key_writes) / Uptime    
(Key_reads + Key_writes) / Uptime
(Table_locks_waited) / Uptime
(Subquery_cache_miss) / Uptime    
(Subquery_cache_hit) / Uptime
(Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free) / Uptime   
(Qcache_inserts - Qcache_queries_in_cache) / Uptime   
(Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi) / Uptime 
(Com_insert_select + Com_replace_select) / Uptime 
((Innodb_buffer_pool_reads + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed) ) / Uptime  
(Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted) / Uptime  
(Table_open_cache_overflows) / Uptime
(Table_open_cache_misses) / Uptime    
(Table_open_cache_hits) / Uptime 
(binlog_commits) / Uptime
(binlog_group_commits) / Uptime  
(Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use) / Uptime
(Slow_launch_threads) / Uptime    
key_buffer_size / _ram    
innodb_buffer_pool_size / _ram    
(key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) / _ram   
table_cache  
table_open_cache 
Open_tables / table_cache
Open_tables / table_open_cache    
open_files_limit / table_cache    
open_files_limit / table_open_cache   
open_files_limit 
innodb_open_files
query_cache_type 
query_cache_size 
Qcache_free_memory / query_cache_size 
Qcache_free_blocks * 4096 / query_cache_size  
Qcache_hits / Qcache_inserts 
Qcache_hits / (Qcache_hits + Com_select)  
Qcache_total_blocks * query_cache_min_res_unit / Qcache_queries_in_cache    
Qcache_queries_in_cache  
Table_locks_waited / (Table_locks_immediate + Table_locks_waited)  
Created_tmp_disk_tables / (Created_tmp_disk_tables + Created_tmp_tables)    
min(max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size)  
max_heap_table_size  
tmp_table_size   
tmp_table_size * max_connections  
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key  
Handler_read_rnd_next / Handler_read_rnd  
(Com_select + Qcache_hits) / (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace)   
Com_rollback / Com_commit
(Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit  
Select_full_join / Com_select
Select_range / Com_select
Select_range_check / Com_select   
Select_scan / Com_select 
sort_buffer_size 
log_slow_queries 
slow_query_log   
slow_query_log_file  
long_query_time  
Slow_queries / Questions 
wait_timeout 
max_connections  
Max_used_connections / max_connections    
Questions / Connections  
Com_change_db / Connections   
Aborted_clients / Connections
Aborted_connects / Connections    
max_connect_errors   
thread_cache_size
Threads_cached   
Threads_connected / max_connections   
Threads_running - 1  
Threads_created / Connections
Threads_running / thread_cache_size   
slow_launch_time 
connect_timeout  
Slave_IO_Running 
Slave_SQL_Running
Seconds_Behind_Master
Last_error   
log_slave_updates
log_slow_slave_statements
binlog_format    
expire_logs_days 
Seconds_behind_master
read_only    
max_allowed_packet   
slave_max_allowed_packet 
net_buffer_length
join_buffer_size 
read_buffer_size 
read_rnd_buffer_size 
tmp_table_size   
tmp_table_size * max_connections  
myisam_sort_buffer_size  
sort_buffer_size 
read_buffer_size 
max_length_for_sort_data 
bulk_insert_buffer_size  
log_bin  
innodb_buffer_pool_size  
innodb_thread_concurrency
innodb_flush_method  
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_file_format   
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg 
innodb_lock_wait_timeout 
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins   
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written / Innodb_dblwr_writes  
innodb_checksums 
tx_isolation 
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size   
innodb_force_recovery
innodb_commit_concurrency
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog    
binlog_cache_size
Binlog_cache_disk_use / Binlog_cache_use  
(binlog_cache_size * max_connections) / _ram  
innodb_buffer_pool_size  
innodb_buffer_pool_size / _ram    
(key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) / _ram   
innodb_buffer_pool_instances 
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size    
innodb_old_blocks_pct
innodb_old_blocks_time    
(Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_pages_read) / ((Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_pages_read) + (Key_writes + Key_reads)) 
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    
Innodb_pages_read / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests   
Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   
1 - Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead  
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   
innodb_log_buffer_size    
Innodb_log_waits / Innodb_log_writes  
Innodb_log_writes / Innodb_log_write_requests 
innodb_log_files_in_group
innodb_log_file_size 
innodb_log_file_size * innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_buffer_pool_size 
Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group
Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size  
Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written
innodb_fast_shutdown 
innodb_adaptive_checkpoint    
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit    
innodb_doublewrite   
sync_binlog  
innodb_fast_shutdown 
innodb_adaptive_hash_index    
innodb_thread_concurrency
innodb_io_capacity   
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct    
innodb_read_io_threads    
innodb_write_io_threads  
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit_session    
key_buffer_size / _ram    
Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size  
(Key_writes + Key_reads) / ((Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_pages_read) + (Key_writes + Key_reads))  
Key_reads / Key_read_requests
Key_writes / Key_write_requests   
Table_locks_waited / (Table_locks_immediate + Table_locks_waited)  
table_lock_wait_timeout  
table_lock_wait_timeout  
min(max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size)  
myisam_max_sort_file_size
read_buffer_size 
read_rnd_buffer_size 
myisam_sort_buffer_size  
myisam_recover_options    
bulk_insert_buffer_size  
character_set_client 
character_set_connection 
character_set_results
character_set_server 
default_character_set
Ssl_finished_accepts 
performance_schema   
ft_min_word_len  
init_connect 
init_file    
init_slave   
large_pages  
locked_in_memory 
log_warnings 
old_passwords    
optimizer_prune_level
optimizer_search_depth    
optimizer_switch 
(Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions 
skip_name_resolve
have_symlink 
local_infile 
log_warnings 
optimizer_search_depth    
innodb_open_files
innodb_adaptive_flushing 
tmpdir   
Uptime   
Uptime_since_flush_status
fppbar   
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode 
innodb_flush_neighbors    
innodb_io_capacity   
Key_reads + Key_writes    
Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written  
Key_reads + Key_writes    
Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written  
max_heap_table_size  
Qcache_not_cached / (Qcache_hits + Com_select + Qcache_not_cached) 
table_open_cache_instances    
version  
Qcache_free_blocks / Qcache_total_blocks  
(query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache 
query_alloc_block_size    
query_prealloc_size  
(query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size 
innodb_stats_auto_update 
query_prealloc_size  
query_alloc_block_size    
expand_fast_index_creation    
innodb_use_sys_malloc
innodb_lazy_drop_table    
innodb_concurrency_tickets    
fast_index_creation  
innodb_rollback_on_timeout    
thread_handling  
thread_pool_size 
innodb_recovery_update_relay_log  
eq_range_index_dive_limit
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size 
binlog_commits   
binlog_group_commits 
read_buffer_size / max_allowed_packet 
innodb_ft_total_cache_size    
record_buffer    
innodb_random_read_ahead 
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead  
innodb_buffer_pool_populate   
flush_caches 
numa_interleave  
innodb_strict_mode   
(Queries-Questions)/Queries   
Subquery_cache_hit / ( Subquery_cache_hit + Subquery_cache_miss )  
table_definition_cache    
host_cache_size  
open_files_limit 
table_definition_cache    
back_log
innodb_page_size 
log_slow_admin_statements
log_slow_slave_statements
innodb_log_files_in_group
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit    
binlog_format    
auto_increment_increment 
simplified-binlog-gtid-recovery   
wsrep_sync_wait  
wsrep_provider_options    
wsrep_slave_threads  
wsrep_auto_increment_control 
wsrep_retry_autocommit    
wsrep_causal_reads   
wsrep_on
Uptime - Uptime_since_flush_status    
max_connections  
read_buffer_size 
10 * read_buffer_size
innodb_expand_import 
innodb_import_table_from_xtrabackup   
binlog_error_action  
autocommit   
version  
version_compile_machine  
version_compile_os   
max_heap_table_size / _ram    
join_buffer_size / _ram  
sort_buffer_size / _ram  
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use / Binlog_stmt_cache_use
(binlog_stmt_cache_size * max_connections) / _ram 
binlog_stmt_cache_size    
Com...   
net_buffer_length / max_allowed_packet    
slow_launch_time 
default_storage_engine    
default_tmp_storage_engine    
storage_engine   
transaction_isolation
flush_time   
innodb_stats_auto_recalc 
innodb_stats_on_metadata 
innodb_stats_persistent  
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages  
innodb_checksum_algorithm
binlog_checksum  
read_only    
master_info_repository    
enforce_gtid_consistency 
gtid_mode    
SQL_delay    
slave_parallel_workers    
slave_compressed_protocol
Innodb_deadlocks / Com_commit
innodb_lock_wait_timeout / Queries    
Innodb_history_list_length
```

Comment: (That list changes as new STATUS and VARIABLES values are added.)

Answer (score 0):

For mysql server monitoring you should concern these-
 Mysql server is running or not by command (service mysql status) and by telnet the server that is running or not. You should consider these parameters.

```
ibdata size
no of connections or Threads
reads per second
write per second
cpu load
memory utilization
no of open tables
query per second
insert/update per second
mysql-server uptime
slow queries
flush tables
no of questions
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Nagios and Cacti plugins from Percona.
Show engine innodb status spits out lots of data, not always easy to parse. Percona has a tool for that i believe.

Comment: I know Nagios but the place I worked we are not able to use this. The manual script should be created. My latest question is : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114339/extended-status-vs-show-variables-what-to-monitor