# extended_status vs show variables, what to monitor?

Tags: mysql

I am stuck to monitor one important server MySQL.

First what is the different between : extended_status vs SHOW VARIABLE 
at MySQL?

Which one should we monitor?

I need the actual status of most important parameters (variables) at MySQL
and compare it with the maximum setting of those parameters (variables).

Anyone can explain more about it?

Comment: This blog will give you an idea about what you should monitor in mysql http://blog.webyog.com/2012/09/03/top-10-things-to-monitor-on-your-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

**Tuning**

`SHOW VARIABLES;` gives a list of constant parameters (from my.cnf or defaults).  The only reason to monitor them is to be alerted when one of them is changed.

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` *together with* `SHOW VARIABLES;` *and* the size of RAM can lead to hundreds of things to check.  But I don't see much need to watch them constantly.

In many cases, the 'right' thing to monitor is not `x`, but `x/Uptime` (per second).  Better yet, use deltas.  Sometimes it is `x/y`, often as a percentage.  ("How full is this cache?")  But then it gets tricky -- a "cache" is designed to too many things wanting to be put into the cache.  Sometimes *other* readings answer that.  Example: `Table_open_cache_misses / Uptime > 1/sec indicates that`table_open_cache` should be increased.  But no clue of a new value.

**Slow Log**

What I prefer is to set `long_query_time = 1` and turn on the slowlog, preferably to a `FILE`.  Then use pt-query-digest to find the worst few queries.  Then figure out how to improve them.

When investigating a slow query, I may find

- something mis-tuned (`VARIABLES`)
- missing or inadequate index
- poorly formulated query
- inefficient schema design
- red flags (EAV, UUID, lat-lng, big deletes, pagination using OFFSET, etc); I have blogs showing how to improve them.

**Interpretation**

Unfortunately, neither set of output says "change x to blah".  You can ask limited questions in this forum, or you can look for someone to assist.

I generally find that one shot at each (Tuning and Slowlog) will hold for several months.  (This assumes my advice is taken, and no "new features" are added.)

**Monitoring tools**

I don't have a full list of tools.  Here are a couple (both cost $$)

- Oracle's Enterprise MySQL
- MonYog (limited time trial version is available)